# How To Install Ubuntu Server 14.04 Offline

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, offline

I am having trouble installing Ubuntu Server 14.04 to a PC I am trying to use as a NAS. I have a router for my LAN but no internet access where I live. Without internet I can't connect to an image archive during the initial installation steps.

Even without the Ethernet cable plugged into the NAS the installer tries to detect an Ethernet link and fails. When it fails I have the option of manually configuring a connection or skipping network config until later.

I have tried skipping network config and the installer still wants me to enter an Ubuntu archive mirror. I cannot seem to get passed this point in the install. I have verified the hash and attempted the install using both Ubuntu server 14.1 x64 and 14.04 x64 .iso's to no avail.

I have come across several tutorials and forum posts with people having similar issues but none quite like this one. Every one says to just skip network configuration and it will let you continue but I am not having the same results.

Is there any way to bypass choosing an archive mirror during installation? Or do I need to to try an older version? Its hard but not impossible for me seek out a legacy version to see if the network configuration step can be skipped in an earlier release.

Update: I finally came across the notice regarding updating to 14.04 requiring internet access to an apt repository. I assume that this applies to doing a fresh install as well. I guess I will need to find an older version to install.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I'm in an isolated room with no internet access. When I try to install the image ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso from USB (written to USB thumbdrive with Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.2) and after skipping the network config (after choosing language and keyboard layout), it simply insists on choosing a regional mirror on the internet, and gives me no alternative, and won't continue without connecting to one. I can't find any other image to allow "offline" installation. What can I do?

EDIT: I finally found out, after reading many other posts, that the solution is: It seems that all the Windows imaging tools (I tried 3) can't handle this ISO image correctly. Finally I gave up and went to a coworker with a native Linux PC and he copied the ISO via dd and now everything works offline without demanding a mirror. Apparently the installer is not robust and misleads instead of simply reporting there is a problem with the local media.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change boot mode in BIOS from UEFI to non-UEFI for your USB-drive. This mode selects other image to start, and, obviously, the UEFI version needs network to download files. Or, maybe, in UEFI mode linux kernel doesn't see the original flash drive, and so, doesn't have the local source of files for installing. This forces the install menu to ask for mirror.

Any way, the same iso image acts differently on one real PC and under VirtualBox. Even given order and variety of install actions differs